# Making Directories with Bash Script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, directory

I have the following bash script to make a set of directories, move to that directory, execute some actions (not shown), and move back up to the parent directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e 'dump' ]; then
        rm -r dump
        mkdir dump
        D="dump/var"
else
        mkdir dump
        D="dump/var"
fi

for d in {1..24}

do
echo $D$d
mkdir $D$d/
cd $D$d
cd ..

done
```

When this script is executed,  the result is that odd-numbered directories are made while even-numbered directories throw the error 'No such file or directory'. If I put in the option to make a parent directory, as in `mkdir -p $D$d/`, a nested directory results `dump/var1`, `dump/dump/var2`, `dump/dump/dump/var3`, et cetera.

If I remove the directory changes, `cd $D$d` and `cd ..`, then the script executes without error. If I use absolute paths for the directory, as in `D="/path/to/directory/dump/var"`, then there is 'No such file or directory' for all but the first directory created.

What is happening in the shell?

Comment: Run your script with `bash -x scriptname` to see what it is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core of the issue: your script `cd` back to  `dump`, not to `dump/`'s parent.

On first iteration:

- You start out in `dump`'s parent directory, where `dump/` exists
- `dump/var1` is created
- you `cd` into `dump/var1`.
- when `cd ..` occurs you go back to `dump/`. Current working directory is `dump` and there's only `var1` there, nothing else.

On the second iteration:

- When you try `mkdir dump/var2/` you are in `dump/` and there's only `var1` there. The `dump/` of `dump/var2` is the non-existent path.  Of course it fails. Hence the error message and hence the duplicate `dump/dump/var2` when you use `mkdir -p` flag.
- Your script still does `cd ..`, so before 3rd iteration current working directory changes from `dump/` to `dump/`'s parent.

For 3rd iteration:

- You're inside `dump/`'s parent directory, the path `dump/` exists, hence `mkdir dump/var3` won't fail.
- `cd dump/var3` occurs, then `cd ..`, and what is the current working directory now ? `dump/` , the one level above `dump/var3`, where you try to do `mkdir dump/dump/var4`, but there's only `var1` and `var3` there, no `dump`. The `mkdir` fails, you `cd ..` which goes one level above `dump/`, and the whole thing repeats again.

You can see this clearly when you execute our script with `set -x` for debugging output appended after `#!/bin/bash` line or by doing `pwd` as first command on each iteration of the script.

The way I'd recommend fixing your script is via `cd` into `dump/` first, and then run the for loop. In other words:

```
cd "$D"
for i in {1..24}
do
    mkdir "$i"
    cd "$i"
    # do whatever you want inside "$i"
    cd ..
done
```

Among other things, I'd suggest using `[ -d "dump" ]` instead of `-e`, because that'll help you make sure the file that exists is actually the directory, although this might take extra considerations.